# Android rotate a shape use java code

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a XML format like this:

### XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="45"
      android:toDegrees="45"
      android:pivotX="13%"
      android:pivotY="-40%">
      <shape
        android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
      </shape>
    </rotate>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

I want to implement it use java code without `xml`, how?

Answer (score 1):

OK，now I have know how to do this

java code :

```
View view = new View(getContext());
GradientDrawable iconPlayShape = new GradientDrawable();
iconPlayShape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
iconPlayShape.setColor(Color.WHITE);
RotateDrawable iconPlayRotate = new RotateDrawable();
iconPlayRotate.setFromDegrees(45.0f);
iconPlayRotate.setToDegrees(45.0f);
iconPlayRotate.setPivotXRelative(true);
iconPlayRotate.setPivotYRelative(true);
iconPlayRotate.setPivotX(0.13f);
iconPlayRotate.setPivotY(-0.4f);
iconPlayRotate.setDrawable(iconPlayShape);
iconPlayRotate.setLevel(1);
view.setBackground(iconPlayRotate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of `LayerDrawable`, you can read more about the class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#LayerDrawable%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%5B%5D%29). Provide the class constructor with an array of Drawable objects. In your case the Drawable objects should be of the type `RotateDrawable` (more information [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RotateDrawable.html))